# How to create specific URLs for a search term

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a simple website setup: two PHP pages, the first of which is just a search box and the second displays info based on the search box input from the user. How can I have the second page have a unique URL based on the search? Something like website.com/query=query+goes+here as opposed to all of the URLs being the same website.com/results.php?

Comment: Learn more about .htaccess

Comment: Anything more specific for me here?

Comment: you could do this on 1 page and simply check to see it $_GET['query'] isset, if it is not set, display the plain search box, if it is set, display the results.

Comment: I know I can do it on one page, but for various reasons, I don't want to.

Comment: I could tell you how to do it in the same way blog applications such as wordpress do it. This is simple but involves a database. – Kev just now edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, it's pretty simple. Just use the get form action:

```
<form action="results.php">
Search: <input type="text" name="search"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then get that variable through a $_GET request on your results.php:

```
<?php
$search_term = $_GET['search'];
//do SQL query or whatever else you need to do here
?>
```

Comment: It will not generate url like "website.com/query=query+goes+here"

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what using a $_GET would do for me here...

Answer (score 0):

You can create it with [htacess](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/htaccess_redirect) and [modrewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) of apache.

EDIT:

Just check the link below for generating dynamic URL. It might solve your problem:

[URL Generation](http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewriting-tool.php)

Comment: Just to be sure, you're saying that the way of using a GET style url is to use url-rewriting?

Comment: in get url will be pageName.php?Fildname=value&fieldName=value  and not "website.com/query=query+goes+here"

Comment: There are also some micro frameworks that will handle this for you..  i.e. silex.  so you can do an http get to:query=query+goes+here and it will handle the redirects for you and you just have to parse it.  not necessarily better, but an option if you want to avoid the url rewriting...

Comment: So in order to have unique URLs I will have to dabble in the .htaccess? I presume there is no other way to do this then. All sites that have unique search URLs are doing something with the .htaccess then? (Pardon my ignorance. New to this stuff.)

Comment: @SureshKamrushi - thanks mate. :) I mis read/understood the question.

Comment: @devirkahan: most of the sites are using htaccess or some framework like codeigniter and cakephp (but eventhough they need to have htaccess) to generate dynamic url (in your word Unique urls). Just check the urls given in my post you will have an idea how they are working and how to generate them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

**.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    <IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
        RewriteBase /
    </IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ results.php?query=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```